# Is this undefined behaviour ( working with string literal)

Tags: c, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
   char *s = "Abc";
   
   while(*s)
      printf("%c", *s++);
   
   return 0;
}
```

I have seen this (on a site) as a correct code but I feel this is undefined behavior.

**My reasoning:**

Here `s` stores the address of the string literal `Abc`. So while traversing through the while loop :

- Iteration - 1:

  Here `*(s++)` increments the address stored in `s` by 1 and returns the non-incremented address (i.e the previous/original value of `s`). So, no problem everything works fine and `Abc` is printed.
- Iteration - 2:

  Now `s` points to a completely different address (which may be either valid or not). Now when trying to perform `while(*s)` isn't it `undefined behavior` ?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: The while loops stops at the null terminator.

Comment: The increment doesn't do some wild random modification of the address. It points exactly at the next character in the following iteration.

Comment: better declare `const char *s = "Abc";` as you should not allow to change string literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Iteration - 1:
>
> Here `*(s++)` increments the address stored in `s` by 1 and returns the non-incremented address (i.e the previous/original value of `s`). So, no problem everything works fine and `Abc` is printed.

No, “Abc” is not printed. `%c` tells `printf` to expect a character value and print that. It prints a single character, not a string. Initially, `s` points to the first character of `"Abc"`. `s++` increments it to point to the next character.

> Iteration - 2:
>
> Now `s` points to a completely different address (which may be either valid or not). Now when trying to perform `while(*s)` isn't it `undefined behavior` ?

In iteration 2, `s` is pointing to “b”.

You may have been thinking of some `char **p` for which `*p` had been set to a pointer to `"abc"`. In that case, incrementing `p` would change it to point to a different pointer (or to uncontrolled memory), and there would be a problem. That is not the case; for `char *s`, `s` points to a single character, and incrementing it adjusts it to point to the next character.

Comment: Sorry, I have misunderstood that ```*``` and ```**```. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No. There's no undefined behaviour here.

`*s++` is evaluated as `*(s++)` due to [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) of postfix increment operator than the dereference operator. So the loop simply iterates over the string and prints the bytes and stop when it sees the null byte.

> Now s points to a completely different address (which may be either valid or not). Now when trying to perform while(*s) isn't it undefined behavior ?

No. In the first iteration `s` points to the address at the char `A` and at `b` in the next and at `c` in the next. And the loop terminates when `s` reaches the null byte at end of the string (i.e. `*s` is 0).

Basically, there's no modification of the string literal. The loop is functionally equivalent to:

```
   while(*s) {
      printf("%c", *s);
      s++;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Now s points to a completely different address

Indeed, it is a completely different but well defined address. `s` referenced the next char of the string literal. So it just adds `1` to the pointer.

Because string literal is nul (zero) terminated the `while` loop will stop when `s` will reference it.

There is no UB.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily add 1 to the pointer. It increments the pointer to point to the next char data item in memory.

Comment: @nicomp it adds 1 to the pointer. if 's' is for example `double` it will add 1 to the pointer to double.